# Convolution of 2D functions - Matlab

Tags: integration, matlab, convolution

I need to compute the convolution of two functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$ numerically. Basically, I have two functions, $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$, and I want to compute $f\cdot g$. I have a rectangular domain $[a,b]\times[c,d]$. How do I compute it?

I have tried with Matlab Function **conv2** but maybe I have not understood how it works if it fits the continuous case...any ideas? Thank you very much in advance.

Here is my code. I don't know if it is correct, in particular I don't know how to check the result. Am I computing in the right way the value of conv2 over the discretization grid?

%choose a rectangular domain an Discretization steps dx for variable x and dy for variable y dx=0.5; dy=0.1; x=(-15:dx:15); y=(-10:dy:10);

Nx=length(x); Ny=length(y);

%my function g is g(x,y):= (1/(1+x^2))y %compute the value of g in the grid g=zeros(Nx,Ny); for i=1:Nx for j=1:Ny g(i,j)=(1/(1+x(i)^2))(y(j)); end end

%compute f

y0=2.5; sigmay=sqrt(0.1); sigmax=sqrt(2); for i=1:Nx for j=1:Ny f(i,j)=(1/(2pisigmaxsigmay))exp(-x(i)^2/(2sigmax^2))(exp(-(y(j)+y0)^2/(2sigmay^2))+exp(-(y(j)-y0)^2/(2sigmay^2))); end end

%compute the 2D convolution. %I want to know the value of g*f on the points of my 2d grid

%Is it correct? At the end, do I have to multiply conv_eval for dx and dy?

conv_eval=conv2(g,f,'same');

Comment: Can you show your attempt with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your reply. Here is my code. I don't know if it is correct, in particular I don't know how to check the result. Am I computing in the right way the value of conv2 over the discretization grid?

%choose a rectangular domain an Discretization steps dx for variable x and dy for variable y
dx=0.5;
dy=0.1;
x=(-15:dx:15);
y=(-10:dy:10);

Nx=length(x);
Ny=length(y);

%my function g is g(x,y):= (1/(1+x^2))*y
%compute the value of g in the grid
g=zeros(Nx,Ny);
for i=1:Nx
for j=1:Ny
g(i,j)=(1/(1+x(i)^2))*(y(j));
end
end

%compute f

y0=2.5;
sigmay=sqrt(0.1);
sigmax=sqrt(2);
for i=1:Nx
for j=1:Ny
f(i,j)=(1/(2*pi*sigmax*sigmay))*exp(-x(i)^2/(2*sigmax^2))*(exp(-(y(j)+y0)^2/(2*sigmay^2))+exp(-(y(j)-y0)^2/(2*sigmay^2)));
end
end

%compute the 2D convolution.
%I want to know the value of g*f on the points of my 2d grid

%Is it correct? At the end, do I have to multiply conv_eval for dx and dy?

conv_eval=conv2(g,f,'same');

Comment: You should add this to your question, instead of posting it as an answer.